# CSS Как выровнять блок цены по одной линии с остальными в Magento?

Tags: css, magento

Подскажите, как выровнять блоки? Я так понимаю они должны липнуть к нижнему краю, чтобы все в сетке стали на одном уровне. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сайт где это пробую](http://agestor.ru/pharmacy/capsules.html?mode=grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменить разметку: class="price-box" поместить в class="actions". Тем самым цена будет привязана к нижней части с кнопкой "В корзину".

Answer (score 0):

добавьте  `min-height: 40px;` styles.css строка 4231

```
.products-grid .product-name, .products-list .product-name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    min-height: 40px; /* <!-- добавляем */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!:-) Но этот вариант не подходит к сожалению... Когда в сетке продуктов будет ряд из 4-х коротких имён, то образуется некрасивый отступ.

Comment: а можно ссылку на сайт, где это всё происходит. а то как-то в небе ковырять код не хочется *)

Comment: Под картинкой ссылка...:-) Изначально имя и цена не были в одном диве.

Answer (score 0):

Если `height` не устраивает, то видимо, без небольшого изменения разметки будет не обойтись.
Можно обернуть наименование продукта и цену в отдельный блок (`relative`). Цену соответственно позиционировать (`absolute`) со значением `bottom: 0`

Примерно таким образом:

```css
.price_block {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80px;  
    background: #ccc;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
.price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
h2 {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="price_block">
  <h2><a href="#">MAX 1000</a></h2>
  <div class="price">300,00 руб.</div>
</div>

<div class="price_block">
  <h2><a href="#">GLUCOSAMINE MAX 750</a></h2>
  <div class="price">300,00 руб.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробовал, что-то видимо мешает... Сейчас на сайте отображена попытка...